# How to handle all errors from Python multiple pools?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

to demonstrate problem I've prepared simple code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


class MyError(Exception):

    def __str__(self):
        return repr("Error msg: " + self.args[0])

def pool_function(msg):
    print msg
    raise MyError(msg)
    return 0

def some_function():
    my_pool = Pool(2)
    msg = ['first', 'second']

    my_pool.map(pool_function, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        some_function()
    except MyError, msg:
        print msg
```

In this particular example as output I get:

```
first
second
'Error msg: first'
```

but I need rather:

```
first
second
'Error msg: first'
'Error msg: second'
```

Problem is that on the level of the main function I try to get access to all error messages which are unique, rather than handling it on level of pool_function but I get only first error msg. Unfortunately the real code with which I work is much more complex so is rather hard to do something with the structure of this code which is demonstrated in example. I need some clean and straight forward solution to get all error messages and process it on the level of main function.

Thanks in advice for any solutions.

Comment: `try~except` will stop your program at first raised exception, so the second msg won't have a chance to run. Instead, you should put `try~except` inside `pool_function` and return error msg when exception raised or result if it is successful.

Comment: @dragon2fly You should make that an answer.

Comment: @dragon2fly yes in that case I can show the message but if I want to get this information and process it further then I should rather return it from that function to handle it in main. However as I showed in example the structure is multilevel. My question is rather about the possibility of some language construction solution in which case I shouldn't  worried about how to transfer it to main function.

Comment: if the `pool_function` has `return`, `my_pool.map` will keep that result. So you just need to read the result of `pool_function` as my answer below.  If you need a `full traceback`, you can return `traceback.format_exc()` instead of  `MyError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `try~ except` in your `pool_function` not `__main__`. If no, `__main__` will stop after the first except raised and left no chance for the second one to run. This is following what you are trying:

```
def pool_function(msg):
    print msg
    try:
        raise MyError(msg)
    except:
        return MyError(msg)


def some_function():
    my_pool = Pool(2)
    msg = ['first', 'second']

    return my_pool.map(pool_function, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
       msg= some_function()
    except MyError, msg:
        print msg
```

It works, but seem not a good way, so:

```
def pool_function(msg):
    print msg
    try:
        # do something
        raise MyError(msg)
    except:
        return 0,MyError(msg)
    else:
        return 1,# some result

def some_function():
    my_pool = Pool(2)
    msg = ['first', 'second']
    return return my_pool.map(pool_function, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    msg = some_function()
    for result in msg:
        if result[0]:
            # do something when it run successfully
        elif not result[0]:
            print result[1]
            # do something when it got errors
```